# Why can I not use the command history in minikube ssh

Tags: bash, kubernetes, ssh, minikube, command-history

I have a minikube K8s 1 node cluster on my Windows 10 pc. I can SSH into this cluster using `minikube ssh`.

The problem that I am experiencing is that I can't use the arrow keys to bring back the previous command. I did some looking around and diagnostics:

- `set -o | grep history` gave `history         on`
- `echo $HISTFILE` gave `/home/docker/.bash_history`. This is indeed in the home folder of the user and the file was present after `exit`ing and executing `minikube ssh` again
- `echo $HISTSIZE` and `echo $HISTFILESIZE` both gave 500
- `echo $SHELL` gave `/bin/bash`

All these things tell me that command history should be enabled, but it doesn't seem to be the case.
I tried using both Powershell and cmd to run `minikube ssh`, both with and without Windows Terminal.

Both PowerShell and cmd themselves have a working command history, but once SSHing using minikube, the history in the bash shell doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to get the command history to work after executing `minikube shh`?

**Edit:**
I have tried `minikube ssh --native-ssh=false`, but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 13):

It seems to be a problem with the SSH client you are using. You can try with the *`--native-ssh=false`* option:

```
minikube ssh --native-ssh=false
```

You can also try with different alternatives or with something like the ssh version that comes with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

[There is already an unsolved issue related to this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5666). (Feel free to update)

✌️

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue. I believe that it might have something to do with the arrow keys not being recognized. Had a similar problem when using vim inside minikube when trying to use escape.